# React slice() mutation convert with immer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mutation, immer.js

I have having issues converting this piece of code to not mutate.

I have tried using immer but I am new react and js

```
handleChange(nextField) {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state
    const bookCopy = this.props.value.book.slice()

    bookCopy[selectedIndex].field_book_notes = nextField
    const nextValue = {
      ...this.props.value,
      books: bookCopy,
    }
    this.props.onChange(nextValue)
  }
```

It was suggested to me to use immer to solve the mutation issue.
I've got this far but have no idea how to deal with nextValue = {
      ...this.props.value,
      books: bookCopy,  ...... .etc.

```
handleChange(nextField) {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state
    const bookCopy = product(this.props.value.book) => {

    bookCopy[selectedIndex].field_book_notes = nextField
```

.....

Comment: Are you getting any errors or bugs?

Comment: Hi, no errors but I haven't the code finished yet. I don't know how to cater for this part using immer: const nextValue = {
      ...this.props.value,
      books: bookCopy,
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mutate initial array `this.props.value.book` you should use `map` instead

Try this

```
handleChange(nextField) {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
    const nextValue = {
      ...this.props.value,
      books: this.props.value.book.map((el, index) => {
        if (index !== selectedIndex) return el;
        return {
           ...el,
           field_book_notes: nextField
        }
      }),
    }
    this.props.onChange(nextValue)
  }
```